# Kusto - render timechart with trend line over a dataset already having an aggregation column

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have a function that fetches the total number (let's call this column 'messageCount') of dead-letter messages per each topic/subscription and creates a new record in `traces` table, every day.

What I want to achieve is to render a `timechart` for my workbook, that will show me in the last 7 days the trend/evolution per each topic/subscription, considering the aggregation column above ('messageCount') and also, if possible, a trend line.

On top of what, I want to make use of the hover effect based on my 'messageCount' column that within `App Insights Logs` it shows the value whereas in the `Workbook` it does not.

What I've tried so far:

```
traces
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| extend
    TopicName = tostring(customDimensions["prop__TopicName"]), 
    SubscriptionName = tostring(customDimensions["prop__SubscriptionName"]),
    MessageCount = toint(customDimensions["prop__DlqCount"]),
    ["Topic/subscription"] = strcat(tostring(customDimensions["prop__TopicName"]), '/', tostring(customDimensions["prop__SubscriptionName"]))
| where cloud_RoleName startswith "myCloudName" and message has "customString"
| make-series take_any(MessageCount) on timestamp in range (ago(7d), now(), 1d) by SubscriptionName
| render timechart
```

The above query works fine in the query logs of `Insights` however it does not have the same behavior in the workbook. Any hints/tips? Thanks

**A sample returned by the regular query without the `make-series` operator**

```
timestamp  | topicName | subscriptionName | messageCount
--------------------------------------------------------
10/31/2022 | myTopic1  | mysubscription1  |   915
10/31/2022 | myTopic2  | mysubscription2  |   1023
10/31/2022 | myTopic3  | mysubscription3  |   602
10/30/2022 | myTopic1  | mysubscription1  |   927
10/30/2022 | myTopic2  | mysubscription2  |   1029
10/30/2022 | myTopic3  | mysubscription3  |   608
```

**Edit - hover effect in logs compared to workbook**

`Insights logs` - [image]

`Workbook`  - [image]

Comment: What does it mean "does not have the same behavior in the workbook"?

Comment: is the only question about the tooltip behavior?  from what i can see from the very limited screenshots, i see very similar line charts?  The charts currently used in workbooks do not support popup tooltips (which is why the logs team moved to a new control in their charts).    The workbooks charts only allow to build series by one value as well, so it would default to the first available string column as the series.

Comment: workbooks charts do not currently support a trend line directly.  how others have done this is to union 2 sets of results together, one set that returns individual lines, and another set with a specific series name that calculates the trend line.  You'd then use chart settings -> series tab to customize the label and style of the trendline series of data

Comment: also, why `take_any(MessageCount)` ?  that's taking a random value and using in the chart.  do you want `sum(MessageCount)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to render a timechart for my workbook, that will show me in the last 7 days the trend/evolution per each topic/subscription, considering the aggregation column above ('messageCount') and also, if possible, a trend line.

1. workbooks only supports splitting up of series based on one field (you can customize x, y, and series columns)

   to get a series line in workbooks for each topic+subscription, you'd have to return that combination of fields as one value column, using something like `by strcat( subscriptionName, " - ", topicName )`
2. workbooks does not currently have a way to calculate a trend line from the data.
   Others have created this by running 2 queries on the same data, 1 that calculates individual series data, and another that calculates the trend line, and then using `union` to combine those 2 things into one result.  You can then use `chart settings -> series settings` to customize the label and color of the calculated trend line

   Doing this in a union query also lets the query work inside logs view outside of workbooks as well.

> On top of what, I want to make use of the hover effect based on my 'messageCount' column that within App Insights Logs it shows the value whereas in the Workbook it does not.

Unfortunately, the charting framework that workbooks is currently built on top of does not have tooltips, it only has the hover behavior where the hovered value appears in the bottom "metrics" area.  The logs team built their experiences on a different framework that has different styles and behaviors of legends/hover/etc.

The various teams (portal, logs, workbooks) are working on converging towards similar frameworks but that work is long term and not as simple as we'd like.